# Term or reference for person who makes their problem everyone else's problem

Tags: terminology

For example, a roommate who puts fragile glassware in the middle of the common area. No one can move it, but everyone must tiptoe around it for fear of breaking it.

While this has an element of social expectation, I am looking for a stereotype or literary reference for this sort of individual. It is close to *entitled*, but more self-righteous.

Cheers

Comment: Selfish, maybe?

Comment: Why can nobody move it?

Comment: Because the owner says, "I'll take care of it soon", but does not